# Changing feature in one layer with feature from another layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, line, editing, features

I have a set of data from the UK Ordnance Survey (Zoomstack). It covers the whole of the UK. In the area I am currently interested in, it appears that one road has been incorrectly designated as a local public road. It is a gated private drive to a riding stable/school, but connects to public highways at each end. This could be confusing to those using the end map.

I have a shapefile layer *'Tracks'* on which I have similar drives that I have plotted and want to migrate this one element from layer *'OS_Open_Zoomstack roads_local'* to layer *'Tracks'*.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 7):

You can select the feature, then choose `Edit > Copy Features` and paste it in the target layer with `Edit > Paste Features`.

Ensure the target layer has editing enabled.

[image]

As @J.R commented, delete the feature in the source layer to complete the transition of the feature from the source layer to the target layer.

If you are working with a network, or otherwise have need for a topologically correct target layer, pay heed to @John's advice:

> The copy and paste method is the easiest. My one concern in using it is preserving topology, specifically that it snaps to the highway lines at both ends preferably at vertexes. If the copied line is essentially a copy of the one to be replaced that shouldn't be an issue, but otherwise you might use the topology checker to be sure, or re-snap the ends. Another option is to paste the copied line into your layer then use the merge attributes tool to transfer its attributes to the existing line, and then deleting the copied line.

Comment: Note that will create a copy of the feature, for a complete "displacement " you need to delete the original feature

Comment: The copy and paste method is the easiest.  My one concern in using it is preserving topology, specifically that it snaps to the highway lines at both ends preferably at vertexes.  If the copied line is essentially a copy of the one to be replaced that shouldn't be an issue, but otherwise you might use the topology checker to be sure, or re-snap the ends.  Another option is to paste the copied line into your layer then use the merge attributes tool to transfer its attributes to the existing line, and then deleting the copied line.